# Probability of dependent events. Why is this wrong solution?

Tags: probability

There are 15 balls, 9 of them are new, 6 - used. What is the probability of taking 2 new and 1 used ball? 
While solving by combination number, it's easy - (comb. of 2 out of 9 *comb 1 out of 6)/ comb 3 out of 15 (sorry, dont know how to write).
But I want to solve it as dependent events : N-new, U-used, p - probability, pUN-probability of U, after N happened, PNNU - taking new, new, used; pNNU + pNUN+PUNN +..... there are C(2,9)*C(1,6) combinations - that is what I think the answer is, but it is not right. In my calculations pNUN=pUNN=..all equal..=pN*(pN*(p(UN))*(p(UN)*p(N(UN)). Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we have to regard that you´re drawing the balls without replacement. That means if a new ball is drawn the probability to draw another new ball is $\frac{9-1}{15-1}=\frac8{14}$

So let us draw two new balls ($n$) first and then one used ball ($u$): $nnu$

The probability is $\frac{9}{15}\cdot  \frac{8}{14}\cdot \frac{6}{13}$

But we can also draw the other two orders: $nun$ and $unn$. Both with the same probability like $nnu$. Therefore the probability to draw 2 new balls and one used ball is

$$3\cdot \frac{9}{15}\cdot  \frac{8}{14}\cdot \frac{6}{13}\approx 47.47\%$$

This is equal to what you have written with the binomial coefficients: $\large{\frac{\binom{9}{2}\cdot \binom{6}{1}}{\binom{15}{3}}}$

Comment: yes, thank you, I was calculating it that way (where you write result 47,7 and it is correct), but than i reccal this formula pNUN=pN(pN*(p(UN))*(p(UN)*p(N(UN))=in my case as i (wrongly understand)=9/15*(9/15*6/14)*(9/15*6*14*8/13), and all that times quantity of NUN,UNN,.....taking from 9 new and 6 used, so C(2,9]*C(1,6) i suppose. Something is wrong with strategy...

Comment: Sorry,  but I really cannot interpret your formula. But if you want to use conditional probability we can say that $P("nnu")=P(X_1=n)\cdot P(X_2=n|X_1=n)\cdot P(X_3=u|X_1=n\cap X_2=n)$, where $P(X_1=n)$ is the probabiltiy that a new ball is drawn. And $P(X_2=n|X_1=n)$ is the probability that a new ball is drawn given that a new ball has been drawn before. This is equal to the numbers I´ve posted:  $\frac{9}{15}\cdot  \frac{8}{14}\cdot \frac{6}{13}$ EDIT: I´ve added random variables $X_i$ for the ball of the i-th draw.

Comment: yes, thank you very much, i meant cond. probab. I was using wrong formula, but its 2 am here! :D ve are multiplying by 3 because of when doing nnu we have nnu, unn, nun? why not by C(2,9)*C(1,6)?

Comment: The formula with the binomial coefficients is another way of calculation/thinking. The three ways are included. At (2,9)*C(1,6) you can say you order at the first three places 2 new and 1 used ball ($3=1+2$). And at the places 4-15 you order 7 new and 5 used balls (1$2=7+5$). It looks like $nnu|nnnnnnnuuuuu$. So you multiply the number of orders at the first three places and then multiply the number of orders at the places $4-15$. Please do not accept and unaccept answer. It´s demotivating.

Comment: i accepted and unnaccepted by mistake obviously, why would i want to say by that... Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.